# Hyperledger Fabric (chaincode instantiate) Error: instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I just tried to package chaincode and sign it as indicated in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/chaincode4noah.html#creating-the-package.

I started the first network from "Build Your First Network". I have two organizations with two peers a channel called "mychannel" and five orderers via raft running (everything on Hyperledger Fabric v1.4.1).

I package the chaincode from Org1 like that:

> peer chaincode package -n nextcc -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go -s -S -i "AND('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.admin')" ccpack.out

Then I switch to Org2 to sign the package and install it:

> export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
>
> export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
>
> peer chaincode signpackage ccpack.out signedccpack.out
>
> export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
>
> export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
>
> peer chaincode install signedccpack.out

Then I switch everything back to Org1 again and install the chaincode there as well.

Until here everthing seems to work pretty fine. However if I try to instantiate the chaincode the following happens:

> peer chaincode instantiate -n nextcc -C mychannel -o orderer.example.com:7050 -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","100"]}' -P "AND('Org1MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.peer')" --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/gi
>   thub.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
>
> 2020-03-04 13:02:19.481 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
>
> 2020-03-04 13:02:19.481 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
>
> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy

I tried it a few times. Does anyone have any suggestions about what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the signers are admins of those organizations? You can also try without Org2's `peer chaincode signpackage`; a signature is implicit on `peer chaincode instantiate` and I have observed problems on duplicated signature disambiguation (I suppose you are instantiating from `Org2`; if not, try without `-S` when packaging). Anyway, you can set `FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG` on your orderer and inspect carefully the orderer logs to dig into the problem.

Comment: Step you have mentioned above. i think you don't have installed chaincode in Org1 peer. there for Org1 peer can not endorse transaction.                                             From hyperledger fabric docs You must install the chaincode on each endorsing peer node of a channel that will run your chaincode.

Comment: When i try without -S and then move on to org2 to sign it. I get the error message "invalid signed deployment spec".

Comment: I also tried to instantiate from org2 without signing it before and after installing the package to both peer from both orgs. Still the same error.

Comment: Orderer log on debug is also net very helpful:
error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=4.112364ms